# Centering a text with respect to its div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a centered-text navigation bar. The div (#navBar) is a blue bar that stretches the screen with a 40px height. Inside the div, is an unordered list that has the display: inline property. Also, the clear: both property is used for my other elements not shown here for brevity. Here's my code:

HTML code:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li>Lifestyle</li>
        <li>Science</li>
        <li>Tech</li>
        <li>Strange</li>
        <li>Entertainment</li>
        <li>Society</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navBar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #1D70B7;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#navBar ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#navBar li{
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

I don't understand why my text doesn't align to the center with the text-align property. I also don't understand why my text doesn't align to the center of the bar with the top: 20px property (Considering the height of the bar to be 40px).

Comment: Please, post your completed code(HTML and etc) or provide a demo.

Comment: @alirezasafian code updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```css
#navBar {
  background-color:#1D70B7;
  height:40px;
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;    
}

#navBar ul {
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
#navBar li {
  color:#fff;
  display:inline;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:40px;
  padding:0 15px;    
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li>Lifestyle</li>
    <li>Science</li>
    <li>Tech</li>
    <li>Strange</li>
    <li>Entertainment</li>
    <li>Society</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Explanation**
You should remove the `position: absolute;` and `top: 20px;` from `#navBar ul`. Now the text is on the bar, but not vertically centered. Now you have to set the `line-height` of your `li` to the height of the navbar (40px).

This works! But your `li` elements are not at the horizontaly centered becuase you are using `margin-left` to create some space between the `li` elements. Remove this and add `padding:0 17px;` or `margin:0 17px;`.

**Edit to your comment:**
You have to add `padding:0;` to `#navBar ul` to remove the padding on the left side (example updated).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I increase the right padding to let's say 55px, it seems as though it's not centered exactly. The left most word seems to have more space with respect to the left end-side of the bar, than the right most word with respect to the right end-side of the bar.

Comment: see my explanation. - you should remove the margin right and replace with `padding:0 17px;` or `margin:0 17px;` like the example

Comment: My last comment is with all the corrections you've said. I just see that when I change the value of the right padding to 55px, I feel like the right side of the text is nearer to the right end of the bar, than the left side of the text is to the left end of the bar.

Comment: ok see my last explanation and updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try this css you don't need to set height for `#navBar`

```
#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1D70B7;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
#navBar ul {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

check demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/6499

Answer (score 0):

`ul` has margin and padding by default and you should [reset it by css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). However, `#navBar ul` has `position:absolute;` which is centered by the following style:

```
#navBar ul {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 40px; //height of parent #navBar
}
```

For aligning vertically, you can use `line-height:40px`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/23tad61b/3/)